# How to iterate over several files in several folders on SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, loops

I've got the following directory structure:

- Folder A

  - sub-folder 1

    - sub-folder 1.1

      - **file.xls**
  - sub-folder 2

    - sub-folder 2.1

      - **file.xls**
  - ...

I've used a foreach loop in SSIS in order to iterate over this directory structure and, for each Excel file named exactly **file.xls** I want to import data.

I created the for each loop exactly as in this article http://bi-polar23.blogspot.com/2007/08/loading-multiple-excel-files-with-ssis.html but when I run the package it stops when reaching the first file. Also, I've checked the "Traverse sub-folders" box.

[image: Enumerator Configuration]

Has anyone encountered this behaviour before? And if so, how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your enumerator configuration?

Comment: Do you receive any warnings or errors when you try to run the package?

Comment: Yes, I get this "Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty." several times before it finds the first file, after which it does what is supposed to do, but only for the first file..

Comment: You may want to take a look at the following [article](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/01/foreach-folder-enumerator.html).  The author gives two workarounds for the foreach folder enumeration issue.

Comment: Great @david, it totally did what I needed (with a few tweaks here and there). Is it possible to mark your comment as an answer? If not and you are interested, you could post the same thing as an answer and I'd mark it as THE answer..

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS you could use multiple Foreach Loop Container tasks.

It might be easier to create a batch file using robocopy and executing the .bat file using an Execute Process Task instead of multiple Foreach Loop Container tasks.